# generate unique key based on two column

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice, openoffice-calc

My openoffice file

```
     A                      B
/ALBON ORAL SUSP            16OZ
/ALBON TABLETS 250MG        B500
/AMOXI DROP                 15ML
/AMOXI DROP                 30ML
/ANTIROBE CAPS 25MG         B600
```

I want unique based on two column

```
     D
/ALBON ORAL SUSP           
/ALBON TABLETS 250MG       
/AMOXI DROP 15ML
/AMOXI DROP 30ML
/ANTIROBE CAPS 25MG
```

any filter or formula there
plz help

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption that your data is sorted alphabetically ascending (i.e. A..Z) then all you really need to do is check the next row. If it's the same as the current cell, then you need to append the data from the next column, otherwise just use the data as is.

Specifically, in cell D1 enter the formula:
=IF(A1=A2,A1+" "+B1, A1)

This formula:
 - checks to see if the current cell is the same as the next
 - if it is, then it appends the value of B1 to the end of the value
 - else, it uses the value as it is

Without more sample data and some rudimentary rules it's impossible to tell if this completely answers your question, but based on your data it seems like it'll do the job.

Hope this helps,

Bob.

Comment: In my spreadsheet more then 4000 row and data is not alphabetically ascending. thnx Bob

Comment: The number of rows is not important. However, it must be sorted alphabetically; if this can't be done I don't see a solution as it means that every single row will need to check every single other row in the whole spreadsheet to see if it's unique. This seems to be beyond the scope of OpenOffice Calc and will require the use of a database instead. Perhaps if you submit more sample data I can see a different solution.

Comment: as you suggest, import spreadsheet in Db and complete task. thnx :-)